# How can I customize custom task form in sharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have  master detail  lists in SharePoint.
I created a workflow for items in detail list and create a custom form with collect data from users action.
in this form I have related item to workflow but I want to have a link to its parent item.
how can I do this?

Comment: Is the custom form implemented by ASP.NET or InfoPath?

Comment: I implemented this form by SharePoint designer , I didn't change it in InfoPath yet. is it possible with infoPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `Collect data from a user` action you cannot do this, because SharePoint doesn't let you customize the task for this action. Instead, you can use the `Start custom task process` action to do this. [Here](http://lyndzhang.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/customize-start-custom-task-process-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/) you can find how use `Start custom task process` instead of `Collect data from a user` and how to customize the InfoPath form which SharePoint creates for the task.

For passing workflow or items values to the task form fields, go to the task process page by clicking on the task name on the workflow editor page, then in the customization section click on the 'Change the behavior of a single task' in the 'Before a Task is Assigned' step you can set task form field to what you want.